# How to add string to cat result in bash?

Tags: bash

File info has some certain info on a line starting with myline. Im trying to pass it to a script like this:

```
bash myscript `cat info | grep myline`
```

This works well. Script gets "myline" as first argument. But now i want to add a "w" at the end of that. I tried

```
bash myscript `cat info | grep myline`w
```

This is already problematic, the script gets "wyline" as first argument.

And now the next step is that i actually want to have an if statement whether i want to add w or not. Tried this:

```
bash myscript `cat info | grep myline``[ "condition" == "condition"] && echo "w"`
```

This works the same way. Script gets "wyline" as first argument.

So I have two questions:
1) How to fix the "wyline" result to get desired "mylinew"
2) Is there a better way to write this if statement after cat?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use backticks `, use `$(...)` instead. [bash hackers obsolete deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)

`cat file | grep` is a useless use of `cat` [useless use of cat award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Just `grep file`.

Just quote the result and add `w`:

```
myscript "$(grep myline info)w"
```

You can add a trailing `w` to the last line of input with `sed`:

```
myscript "$(grep myline info | sed '$s/$/w/')"
```

I would advise to always quote your variable expansions.

> Script gets "wyline" as first argument.

Your input file has dos line endings. Inspect output with `cut -v` or `hexdump -C` or `xxd`. Use `dos2unix` and remove carriage return characters.